# Why does the output of a register bank( designed by me in verilog) change after two clock cycles, even if input changes every clock cycle?

Tags: verilog

I have designed a register bank (pipeline register) to be used in a pipeline-architecture. The code of the register is:

```
module if_id(   input clk,
                input [31:0] newPC, 
                input [31:0] instr, 

                output reg [31:0] newPCout, 
                output reg [31:0] instrOut);

    reg [63:0] temp;
    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        temp <= {newPC,instr};
    end
    always @ (negedge clk) begin
        newPCout <=  temp[63:32];
        instrOut <= temp[31:0];
    end
endmodule
```

[image: GTKwave Graphs for inputs and outputs of the given module]

Now in this waveform, **instrOut** changes every 2nd clock cycle. Why? 
I cannot seem to find the fault in the code, according to me the output should change at every negedge of the clock.

---

This is the image of the test bench, pipe1 is the instance of if_id module.

````
module tb(); // tb for fetch
    //fetch
    reg [31:0] baddress;
    reg clk;
    reg pcsource;

    //fetch
    wire [31:0]newpc;
    wire [31:0]instr;

    //if_id
    wire [31:0]newpcpipe1;
    wire [31:0]instrpipe1;

    //decode
    wire [31:0]rd1,rd2;
    wire [31:0]imm;
    wire [4:0]rs,rt,rd;
    wire [5:0]opcode;

    //main Control
    wire [3:0]ex;
    wire [2:0]mem;
    wire [1:0]wb;

    //id_ex
    wire [3:0] exo;
    wire [1:0]wbo;
    wire [2:0]memo;
    wire [31:0] rd1o;
    wire [31:0] rd2o;
    wire [31:0] immo;
    wire [4:0]  rso;
    wire [4:0]  rto;
    wire [4:0]  rdo;
    wire [31:0] newPCo;

    //ex
    wire [31:0]tPc;
    wire[31:0] AluRes;
    wire [4:0] regDstAdd;
    wire zero;

    //ex_mem
    wire [1:0]wb_m;
    wire [2:0]mem_m;
    wire zero_m;
    wire [31:0] AluOut_m;
    wire [4:0] regdst_m;
    wire [31:0] newPC_m;

    //mem
    wire PCSrc;
    wire [31:0] aluouto;

    //mem_wb
    wire regWrite;
    wire [31:0] AluOut_w;
    wire [4:0] regdst_w;

    fetch fetch1(clk,pcsource,baddress,newpc,instr);
    if_id pipe1(clk,newpc,instr,newpcpipe1,instrpipe1);

    decode decode1(clk,instrpipe1,AluOut_w,regdst_w,regWrite,rd1,rd2,imm,rs,rt,rd,opcode);
    MainControl mc1(opcode,ex,mem,wb);
    id_ex pipe2(clk,wb,mem,ex,newpcpipe1,rd1,rd2,imm,rs,rt,rd,exo,wbo,memo,rd1o,rd2o,immo,rso,rto,rdo,newPCo );

    ex ex1(newPCo,rd1o,rd2o,immo,rto,rdo,exo,tPc,AluRes,regDstAdd,zero);
    ex_mem pipe3(clk,wbo,memo,tPc,AluRes,zero,regDstAdd,wb_m,mem_m,zero_m,AluOut_m,regdst_m,newPC_m);

    mem mem1(mem_m,AluOut_m,zero_m,PCSrc,aluouto);
    mem_wb pipe4(clk,wb_m,AluOut_m,regdst_m,regWrite,AluOut_w,regdst_w);


    initial begin
        $dumpfile("fetch.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0,tb);
    end

    initial begin
        clk = 1'b0;
        forever #5 clk = ~clk;
    end
    initial begin
        //$monitor($time," clk = %b \n ,instr=%b, newPC = %b,",clk,instrpipe1,newpcpipe1);
        #10 baddress = 32'b0; pcsource = 0;
        #200 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```
````

Comment: It's obvious that `temp` is only changing on every other clock, which is weird. Show us the code for your testbench.

Comment: [Test Bench](https://imgur.com/LGI6P2A) This is the image of the test bench, pipe1 is the instance of if_id module.

Comment: Not as an image! Paste the actual code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the waveform your `instr` is weird/wrong.

It is picked-up in `tmp` at the same clock edge that it changes. This is indicative that `instr` change at or before the clock edge. Not after.

Did you use this in your test-bench/code?

```
always @ (posedge clk)
   instr = some_test_value;
```

instead of?

```
always @ (posedge clk)
   instr <= some_test_value;
```